# Elmのネイティブモジュールが見つからないと言われる

Tags: javascript

既存のJSライブラリをElmアプリから使うため、ネイティブモジュールでラッピングしました。しかし、最後のelm-makeでコケます。

```
# 単体コンパイルをテストするコマンド。
# 実際はwebpackとelm-webpack-loaderでコンパイルするようにセットアップしてある
$ elm-make app/frontend/elm/Mermaid.elm
I cannot find find module 'Native.Mermaid'.

Module 'Mermaid' is trying to import it.

Potential problems could be:
  * Misspelled the module name
  * Need to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json
```

ファイル配置:

```
$ find app/frontend/elm/ -iname "Mermaid.*"
app/frontend/elm//Mermaid.elm
app/frontend/elm//Native/Mermaid.js
```

中身: Mermaid.elm

```hs
module Mermaid where
{-| ...
-}

import Html exposing (Html)
import Native.Mermaid

...
```

中身: Native/Mermaid.js

```js
// setup
Elm.Native = Elm.Native || {};
Elm.Native.Mermaid = Elm.Native.Mermaid || {};

// definition
Elm.Native.Mermaid.make = function(localRuntime) {
  'use strict';

  if ('values' in Elm.Native.Mermaid) {
    return Elm.Native.Mermaid.values;
  }

  ...

  return Elm.Native.Mermaid.values = {
    toHtmlWith: F2(toHtmlWith)
  };
};
```

elm-markdownライブラリをほぼコピペしたようなものなのですが、どうすればコンパイルが通るようになるでしょうか

Answer (score 2):

ネイティブモジュールを含むパッケージは、そのことをelm-package.json内で明示する必要があります。

```
...
"exposed-modules": [],
"native-modules": true, // <---
"dependencies": {
  ...
```

これは、JavaScriptの世界はElmの型チェックが及ばず、副作用も起こし放題で危険なため、JavaScriptを含むパッケージを区別して扱えるようにするためです。ネイティブモジュールを含むパッケージは公式パッケージレポジトリにアップロードする際にレビューをはさむようにもなっています。